# JavaFX how to remove the borders from button

Tags: java, button, javafx, border

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y76Fl.png

On this picture on left side - running java program, and right side - Scene builder layout.

This is my github code: https://github.com/captsmile/calc

Comment: include the code into the post, rather than an external link

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following code in .css file

```
.button
 {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
 }
```

This will make the color of button as the color of your application's background color(due to transparency).

Furthermore you may also apply some effects to make your button looks more cool. To add effects

```
.button:hover 
{
  -fx-background-color: yellow;
} 
.button:pressed
{
  -fx-background-color: brown;
}
```

At the end ,you may attach the case file with your file(suppose index.java file in which you want to apply css) by writing following code in your index.java

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```

Where application.css is the css file with whole css code given above . This application file must be present in your src folder.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this removing border at GridPane

```css
.root{
    -fx-padding: 5;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in scenebuilder

Choose the button by clicking on it.

Then in properties->Style
Choose "-fx-background-color"
and put value as " transparent"

Like this

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by JavaFX CSS selectors on the button.
The answer in this link check it out, and there are also many JavaFX related examples you may interested in:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/button.html